# Laravel Relationship: Trying to get property 'description' of non-object

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, foreign-keys, relational-database

I'm facing against this problem since yesterday.
I have a db table called `resources` have a foreign key linked to another table called `category`.

[image: Screenshot of database tables]

I'm trying to retrieve the `description` field in my blade view, but I get this error:

> Trying to get property 'description' of non-object.

My blade view:

```php
@extends('templates.header')

@section('section')
    <div class="p-10 grid grid-cols-1 sm:grid-cols-1 md:grid-cols-3 lg:grid-cols-3 xl:grid-cols-3 gap-5">
        @foreach($resources as $resource)
            <div class="max-w-sm rounded overflow-hidden shadow-lg">
                {{-- <img class="w-full" src="#" alt="Mountain"> --}}
                <div class="px-6 py-4">
                    <div class="font-bold text-xl mb-2">
                        {{ $resource->name }}
                    </div>
                    <p class="text-gray-700 text-base">
                        {{ $resource->description }}
                    </p>
                </div>
                <div class="px-6 pt-4 pb-2">
                    <span class="inline-block bg-gray-200 rounded-full px-3 py-1 text-sm font-semibold text-gray-700 mr-2 mb-2">{{ $resource->categor->description }}</span>
                    <span class="inline-block bg-gray-200 rounded-full px-3 py-1 text-sm font-semibold text-gray-700 mr-2 mb-2">{{ $resource->status }}</span>
                    <span class="inline-block bg-gray-200 rounded-full px-3 py-1 text-sm font-semibold text-gray-700 mr-2 mb-2">{{ $resource->centerId }}</span>
                    <button type="submit" class="inline-flex justify-center py-2 px-4 border border-transparent shadow-sm text-sm font-medium rounded-md text-white bg-indigo-600 hover:bg-indigo-700 focus:outline-none focus:ring-2 focus:ring-offset-2 focus:ring-indigo-500">
                        Prenota
                    </button>
                </div>
            </div>
        @endforeach
    </div>
@endsection
```

My Resource Model:

```php
namespace App\Models;

use App\Models\Category;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Resource extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'name',
        'description',
        'category',
        'inventoryN',
        'status',
        'centerId',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be cast to native types.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $casts = [
    ];

    public function category()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(Category::class, 'id', 'category');
    }
}
```

My Category Model:

```php
namespace App\Models;

use App\Models\Resource;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Category extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $table = 'categories';

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'description',
    ];

    /**
    * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
    *
    * @var array
    */
    protected $hidden = [
    ];

    /**
    * The attributes that should be cast to native types.
    *
    * @var array
    */
    protected $casts = [
    ];

    public function resource()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Resource::class, 'category');
    }
}
```

And lastly my ResourceController:

```php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Models\Category;
use App\Models\Resource;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class ResourceController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        $resources = Resource::with('category')->get();

        return view('resources', compact('resources'));
    }
}
```

This is a dd of "$resources":
[dd of $resources](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YRnEc.png)

Comment: Because `$resource->category` returns `null` so `$resource->category->description` throw this error

Comment: if I use "$resource->category" I can see the id of the category

Comment: I think there needs to be a default value in either of the tables.

Comment: Also, it's probably a better idea to change the schema so that `category` (the foreign ID) is actually `category_id`...

Comment: [the category table](https://gyazo.com/4e406a0762d18889dff04044d7931e78) [the resources table](https://gyazo.com/ec41deb6df679e8744a9b37121cddb16)

Comment: @JustCarty I've changed as you suggest. The funny thing is when i restart the site and go on the requested view my pc crash for some reason. Then when I changed back to the initial column name all works fine.

Comment: @Maximusrain well of course it broke, you need to update the Models to reflect the change. If you make that change, not only does it comply with an accepted standard, but also you can write your `Resource` model as `$this->hasOne(Category::class);` and the `Category` model as `$this->belongsTo(Resource::class);` which is just easier to read and maintain.

Comment: @JustCarty ok I'll try

Comment: @JustCarty Thanks for your suggestion. I finally fix it. The problem was with columns names. I really appreciate your help

Comment: @Maximusrain No worries, I have turned my comments into answer format for your if you want to update / accept. It just helps so that this question won't appear as unanswered in the search.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a few mistakes here.

The first is in the Blade. You need to fix a typo

```php
$resource->categor->description
// should be
$resource->category->description
```

Then I recommend changing your schema by changing your resources column from `category` to `category_id`.
This will help Laravel auto populate the values in the below snippets.

Next, you need to fix your relationships.

In the Resources model, you need

```php
public function category()
{
    return $this->hasOne(Category::class);
}
```

I have removed the second and third parameters, these are autofilled by Laravel; and since you are using Laravel's naming schemes, you don't need it.
What you had previously was stating that the table was the singular variant of category, which it wasn't.

Then you need to change your Category model to

```php
public function resource()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Resource::class);
}
```

The reason this was failing is because Laravel was returning `null`, because the column names weren't quite correct.

---

It's easier to just have a more standard naming structure in your Database as it helps other developers, and makes your life easier when using Laravel.

Answer (score 1):

There is a typo in your category viewing. I think that's the problem.

```
{{ $resource->categor->description }}

vs. 

{{ $resource->category->description }}
```

Comment: I've missed a y, but still get the same error

Comment: Could you add the entire error? Usually there are line numbers which you can look into, to pinpoint the problem. 
Maybe there is no category relation, so the `$resource->category` result is `null` or empty.